# CiviCase css problem (Joomla version) after upgrade to 4.7.14

Tags: joomla, civicase, css, 4.7.14

There is a problem with css class "label" in CiviCase. This affects the CiviCase dashboard and custom fields in the Case view panel. I think this only affects the Joomla version of CiviCRM 4.7.14.

Comment: This isn't a question...

Comment: You don't need to "just comment" jira issues here, I think.

Comment: Jem - thanks for adding this. You should be able to add the second 3 sentences (starting "more details" as an Answer and then 'accept' it. If you do so, perhaps you could outline in your Question what the outcome of the problem is (ie how is it observed)

Comment: petednz - it's so long ago that I can't remember how the error manifested itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed in version 4.7.16. More details [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19734). If for some reason you need a quick fix for version 4.7.14, comment out the last 10 lines of css/joomla.css.